# Groupby and reverse calculation of one column based on pct_change in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame like `df1` in which has four columns, suppose all the `city`s have date range from `2019-01-01` to `2019-07-01`, I would like to groupy `city` and calculating `price` based on its value in `2019-07-01` and `pct_change`:

```
   city        date  price  pct_change
0    bj  2019-01-01    NaN         NaN
1    bj  2019-02-01    NaN       -0.03
2    bj  2019-03-01    NaN        0.16
3    bj  2019-04-01    NaN        0.07
4    bj  2019-05-01    NaN        0.19
5    bj  2019-06-01    NaN       -0.05
6    bj  2019-07-01    6.0       -0.02
7    gz  2019-01-01    NaN         NaN
8    gz  2019-02-01    NaN        0.03
9    gz  2019-03-01    NaN        0.00
10   gz  2019-04-01    NaN        0.03
11   gz  2019-05-01    NaN        0.00
12   gz  2019-06-01    NaN        0.06
13   gz  2019-07-01    NaN        0.07
14   gz  2019-08-01    8.9       -0.02
15   sh  2019-02-01    NaN        0.04
16   sh  2019-03-01    NaN       -0.04
17   sh  2019-04-01    NaN       -0.04
18   sh  2019-05-01    NaN       -0.04
19   sh  2019-06-01    NaN       -0.04
20   sh  2019-07-01    NaN       -0.01
21   sh  2019-08-01    7.5       -0.01
22   sz  2019-02-01    NaN       -0.03
23   sz  2019-03-01    NaN        0.10
24   sz  2019-04-01    NaN       -0.04
25   sz  2019-05-01    NaN       -0.16
26   sz  2019-06-01    NaN        0.12
27   sz  2019-07-01    7.0        0.00
```

For example, in Excel, I can calculate in reverse the fifth `row`'s `price` value by `6.0/(1+(-0.02)) = 6.12`, 4th `price` by `6.12/(1+(-0.05)) = 6.44`, etc.

Is it possible I get an expected result (not necessary to precisely same) like `df2` in Python?

```
   city        date  price  pct_change
0    bj  2019-01-01   4.49       -0.03
1    bj  2019-02-01   4.34        0.16
2    bj  2019-03-01   5.04        0.07
3    bj  2019-04-01   5.39        0.19
4    bj  2019-05-01   6.43       -0.05
5    bj  2019-06-01   6.11       -0.02
6    bj  2019-07-01   6.00        0.05
7    gz  2019-01-01   7.58        0.03
8    gz  2019-02-01   7.79        0.00
9    gz  2019-03-01   7.80        0.03
10   gz  2019-04-01   8.04        0.00
11   gz  2019-05-01   8.04        0.06
12   gz  2019-06-01   8.52        0.07
13   gz  2019-07-01   9.10       -0.02
14   gz  2019-08-01   8.90        0.00
15   sh  2019-01-01   8.81        0.04
16   sh  2019-02-01   9.16        0.02
17   sh  2019-03-01   8.79       -0.04
18   sh  2019-04-01   8.43       -0.12
19   sh  2019-05-01   8.06       -0.04
20   sh  2019-06-01   7.70        0.07
21   sh  2019-07-01   7.60       -0.01
22   sh  2019-08-01   7.50        0.06
23   sz  2019-01-01   7.30       -0.03
24   sz  2019-02-01   7.10        0.10
25   sz  2019-03-01   7.80       -0.04
26   sz  2019-04-01   7.45       -0.16
27   sz  2019-05-01   6.28        0.12
28   sz  2019-06-01   7.02        0.00
29   sz  2019-07-01   7.00       -0.04
```

Please note if I have `df3` as follows:

```
   city        date  price
0    bj  2019-01-01   4.49
1    bj  2019-02-01   4.34
2    bj  2019-03-01   5.04
3    bj  2019-04-01   5.39
4    bj  2019-05-01   6.43
5    bj  2019-06-01   6.11
6    bj  2019-07-01   6.00
7    gz  2019-01-01   7.58
8    gz  2019-02-01   7.79
9    gz  2019-03-01   7.80
10   gz  2019-04-01   8.04
11   gz  2019-05-01   8.04
12   gz  2019-06-01   8.52
13   gz  2019-07-01   9.10
14   gz  2019-08-01   8.90
15   sh  2019-01-01   8.81
16   sh  2019-02-01   9.16
17   sh  2019-03-01   8.79
18   sh  2019-04-01   8.43
19   sh  2019-05-01   8.06
20   sh  2019-06-01   7.70
21   sh  2019-07-01   7.60
22   sh  2019-08-01   7.50
23   sz  2019-01-01   7.30
24   sz  2019-02-01   7.10
25   sz  2019-03-01   7.80
26   sz  2019-04-01   7.45
27   sz  2019-05-01   6.28
28   sz  2019-06-01   7.02
29   sz  2019-07-01   7.00
```

I can get `df2` by the following code:

```
data = data.set_index(['city', 'date']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.date
data = data.sort_values(by = ["city", "date"])
data['pct_change'] = data.groupby('city').price.pct_change()
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: If you want to `groupby` then row 6 should not have a value since row 7 is the next group, so it cannot have a pct_change

Comment: If `row`s in the end or in the begining without `pct_change` or `price`, that's understandable. The problem is I can calculate and fill `price` column in `df1` in excel, but I don't know how to do it in Python.

Comment: because of the rounding values in the column `pct_change`, you can't get back the exact same values

Comment: Not necessary to be exact same values, if it's nearby the precise values, that's OK for me.

Comment: I update more about my calculation logic to make it clear, please check, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html) in a `groupby`, but you need to reverse twice the data with `[::-1]` such as:

```
df1['estimate_price'] = (df1.fillna({'price':1})\ #for later multiplication
                            .groupby('city')\
                            .apply(lambda x: (x['price']/(1 + x['pct_change'].shift(-1).fillna(0)))[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])\
                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))#to use index alignment
print (df1)
   city        date  price  pct_change  estimate_price
0    bj  2019-01-01    NaN         NaN        4.498224
1    bj  2019-02-01    NaN       -0.03        4.363278
2    bj  2019-03-01    NaN        0.16        5.061402
3    bj  2019-04-01    NaN        0.07        5.415700
4    bj  2019-05-01    NaN        0.19        6.444683
5    bj  2019-06-01    NaN       -0.05        6.122449
6    bj  2019-07-01    6.0       -0.02        6.000000
7    gz  2019-01-01    NaN         NaN        7.547443
8    gz  2019-02-01    NaN        0.03        7.773866
9    gz  2019-03-01    NaN        0.00        7.773866
10   gz  2019-04-01    NaN        0.03        8.007082
11   gz  2019-05-01    NaN        0.00        8.007082
12   gz  2019-06-01    NaN        0.06        8.487507
13   gz  2019-07-01    NaN        0.07        9.081633
14   gz  2019-08-01    8.9       -0.02        8.900000
15   sh  2019-02-01    NaN        0.04        9.009609
16   sh  2019-03-01    NaN       -0.04        8.649225
17   sh  2019-04-01    NaN       -0.04        8.303256
18   sh  2019-05-01    NaN       -0.04        7.971125
19   sh  2019-06-01    NaN       -0.04        7.652280
20   sh  2019-07-01    NaN       -0.01        7.575758
21   sh  2019-08-01    7.5       -0.01        7.500000
22   sz  2019-02-01    NaN       -0.03        7.045905
23   sz  2019-03-01    NaN        0.10        7.750496
24   sz  2019-04-01    NaN       -0.04        7.440476
25   sz  2019-05-01    NaN       -0.16        6.250000
26   sz  2019-06-01    NaN        0.12        7.000000
27   sz  2019-07-01    7.0        0.00        7.000000
```

Comment: Great thank you very much, I’ll try with my real data and let you know.

Comment: I have tried with my real data, I get some enormal `estimate_price`, such as: `415908.158347`, `38087600.424192`, etc, I checked `price` and `pct_change`, they are normal values, the price in `2019-08-01` is 79 and `pct_change` is less 20%.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon without the data, not sure. few things to check are that in pct_change the number are well below 1, because if it is 20 for 20% and not 0.2 then the calculation increase. if some values in price, except the last one per group are not nan so not filled with 1 then result could grow fast as well

Comment: so if you assign the estimated price to the column price and run again the code, then all the values are already filled which will increase the result of cumprod

Comment: I have replaced `pct_change` greater than 0.2 with 0.05 and less than -0.2 wih -0.05, so I think your second assuption is correct, there are some values in price.

Comment: I got an error `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon not really like this, maybe try to reset_index before doing anything but be aware that you could loose some information so keep the original index in a variable in case you need it

Comment: It generate another error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`, can you help?

Comment: Sorry, any ideas when I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1`?

Comment: @ahbon no really, except that there is mismatch between the size of what you try to assign and where you want it in. like this it is difficult to say what is wrong