# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1 or NaNs when set calculated results as one column values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728684/groupby-and-reverse-calculation-of-one-column-based-on-pct-change-in-python) to the following dataframe:

```
  city        date       pct          id    price
0   bj  2019-06-01  0.010002  1210217342      NaN
1   bj  2019-07-01  0.009999  1210217342      NaN
2   bj  2019-08-01  0.009996  1210217342      NaN
3   bj  2019-09-01  0.010000  1210217342      NaN
4   bj  2019-10-01  0.010000  1210217342      NaN
5   bj  2019-11-01  0.000000  1210217342      NaN
6   bj  2019-12-01  0.002683  1210217342      NaN
7   bj  2020-01-01 -0.012374  1210217342      NaN
8   bj  2020-02-01 -0.018702  1210217342  35000.0
```

When I use the code below, I get the correct result:

```
df.fillna({'price':1})\
                            .groupby('id')\
                            .apply(lambda x: (x['price']/(1 + x['pct'].shift(-1).fillna(0)))[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])\
                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
              0             1  ...             7        8
0  34612.079278  34958.180065  ...  35667.054491  35000.0
```

But when I set them as value of `price`,

```
df['price'] = (df.fillna({'price':1})\
                            .groupby('id')\
                            .apply(lambda x: (x['price']/(1 + x['pct'].shift(-1).fillna(0)))[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])\
                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print(df)
```

It seems didn't work out because some are still `NaN`s:

```
   city        date       pct          id         price
0   bj  2019-06-01  0.010002  1210217342  34612.079278
1   bj  2019-07-01  0.009999  1210217342           NaN
2   bj  2019-08-01  0.009996  1210217342           NaN
3   bj  2019-09-01  0.010000  1210217342           NaN
4   bj  2019-10-01  0.010000  1210217342           NaN
5   bj  2019-11-01  0.000000  1210217342           NaN
6   bj  2019-12-01  0.002683  1210217342           NaN
7   bj  2020-01-01 -0.012374  1210217342           NaN
8   bj  2020-02-01 -0.018702  1210217342           NaN
```

Or if I try to create new column `new_price` with it:

```
df['new_price'] = (df.fillna({'price':1})\
                            .groupby('id')\
                            .apply(lambda x: (x['price']/(1 + x['pct'].shift(-1).fillna(0)))[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])\
                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

it generates an error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1`.

BTW, when there are multiple `city` and `id` groups, the code above works smoothly.

Someone could help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From your error message it just seems like the data that you want to use to replace the column `df['new_price']` is in the wrong shape. I.e. it seems like you have 1 row with 9 columns instead of one column with 9 rows. You can use `df.transpose()` to transpose your current row-based data into columns to allow you to add it to your dataframe. [Link to docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)